# Does Restart-Service run asynchronously?

Tags: powershell

Does Restart-Service run asynchronously? I've searched the question online but found nothing. For the tests I've done, the services quickly started to be in running state, making it hard to judge if the command runs asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Restart-Service` runs synchronously. However, if you have services like Java Enterprise containers your actual services my still be starting up even though the Windows service already reports "Running".